# ReactRouter "on change" event?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to install an analytics handler on my single page app, and would like to capture every route change under the main route. I recognize that ReactRouter offers an `onEnter` route event; however, this would require me to separately install the handler on each route. I could create a subclass of Route that automatically has `onEnter` populated, but then I would not be able to override `onEnter` and still keep the analytics tracking handler.

What would be the best way to listen for any change within a given root Route?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the react-router [willTransitionTo](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/57543eb41ce45b994a29792d77c86cc10b51eac9/doc/03%20Components/Route%20Handler.md#willtransitiontotransition-params-query-callback) static function to detect a route change and emit the `transition.path` in your `ga()` function call, like so:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Router.State],
  statics: {
    willTransitionTo: function(transition, params, query, props) {
      ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': transition.path});
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RouteHandler />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

A more complete example can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29932412/1774183).

Answer (score 3):

The answer was (figuratively) staring me in the face.

When you start the Router, you call `Router.run(routes, callback)`. The callback is called on every route change. Therefore, the following code works the way I wanted:

```
Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  doSomethingAnalytics(document.location.hash);
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body.querySelector('#content'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**React: v15.x, React Router: v4.x**

*components/core/App.js:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


class LocationListener extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleLocationChange(this.context.router.history.location);
    this.unlisten = 
this.context.router.history.listen(this.handleLocationChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unlisten();
  }

  handleLocationChange(location) {
    // your staff here
    console.log(`- - - location: '${location.pathname}'`);
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}    

export class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <LocationListener>
         ...
        </LocationListener>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

*index.js:*

```
import App from 'components/core/App';

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

this function is called everytime the route is changed

```
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

history.listen((location)=>{
  console.log(location)
});
```